# Ibrowser installation - the icon isn't shown

Tags: image, tinymce

I'm trying to install ibrowser for tinymce. Here's the config file:

```
$cfg['ilibs'] = array ( // image library path with slashes; absolute to root directory
array (
    'value' => '/Content/articles/',
    'text' => 'Site Pictures',
),
array (
    'value' => '/Content/articles/',
    'text' => 'Gallery',
),
);
```

The code for the tinyMce initialization is this:

```
mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,ibrowser",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "ibrowser,|,insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
```

But the browser icon isn't shown. I set the correct permissions for the needed folders, and nothing. Why is this? There are no errors, everything else is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the version of tinyMce and the version of iBrowser weren't compatible.